# Restricting access to some elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

For a project that will let developers add their own Javascript applications, I need to limit scope of Javascript to a certain `div`. For example, each developer will have access to their own div.

```
<div id="md5_of_a_salt_and_app_id">
    <script>
        /* This area should not be able to modify window element 
         * or other divs than parent one 
         */
    </script>
</div>
```

Is there such possibility?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two well-known possibilities:

**[Google Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)**

> Caja is a
>   Google project for "virtual iframes"
>   based on the principles of
>   object-capabilities. Caja takes
>   JavaScript, HTML, and CSS input and
>   rewrites it into a safe subset of HTML
>   and CSS, plus a single JavaScript
>   function with no free variables. That
>   means **the only way such a function can
>   modify an object** is if it is given **a
>   reference to the object by the host
>   page.**

**[Adsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/)**

> The ADsafe **subset blocks a script from
>   accessing** any global variables or from
>   directly accessing **the Document Object
>   Model or any of its elements**. Instead,
>   ADsafe gives the script access to an
>   ADSAFE object that is provided by the
>   page's server, giving indirect access
>   to the guest code's DOM elements and
>   other page services.

Note that Adsafe doesn't modify scripts, while Caja does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think we will go with ADsafe, or an API that's written on ADsafe.